# A grouping and count select for tabular results in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have 3 tables (one holding results/votes and two are lookup tables) as follows:

### **VOTES**

```
areaid    - which links to an area table to get area name
townid    - which links to a town table to get town name
votingyn  - if a person is voting or not (Y or N)
```

consider the above table having the following test data:

```
1,2,'Y'
1,3,'N'
2,1,'Y'
3,3,'N'
```

.. and so on, areaid multiples, townid multiples and of course a Y or N if voting

So.. I am trying to find the most efficient way to get the following results:

Grouped by areaid, get distinct townid count along with how many Y or N votes
something like (if areadid and townid where hooked up to the lookup tables for the names):

```
area 1,     town1,       voting Y,   voting N
-------------------------------------------------
AREA 1      TOWN 1       23          12
AREA 2      TOWN 2       15          7
```

Not sure if that is clear enough.. any help much appreciated!

Comment: For the test data you included, can you give an example result (ignore the lookup tables for now).  Although, I'm a little twitchy about this design...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do it (untested):

```
SELECT a.Name AS 'Area', t.Name AS 'Town',
  SUM(CASE v.votingyn WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Yes'
  SUM(CASE v.votingyn WHEN 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'No'
FROM VOTES AS v
  JOIN TOWN AS t ON v.townid = t.id
  JOIN AREA AS a ON v.areaid = a.id
GROUP BY (a.Name, t.Name)
```

Comment: Or (with more syntactic sugar): `COUNT(NULLIF(v.votingyn, 'N')) AS Yes, COUNT(NULLIF(v.votingyn, 'Y')) AS No`.

Comment: Thanks for that! forgot you can use the case/when statements in sum... very useful!